# How to average GPS tracks?

Tags: gps

I have GPS data - point cloud in a shapefile. Now I want to average this data and get on output a single GPS track. Here I found [images](http://www.geocomputation.org/2007/1B-Algorithms_and_Architecture1/1B2.pdf) but can't find algorithm. Maybe gdal or postgis can do it? Any advise?

Comment: You mention gdal and PostGIS - are you looking for solutions specifically for those softwares, a particular list, commercial or open source, or any? Related questions include: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23464/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70623/ (an answer links to the same paper you do, and there's further discussion on the method in comments and a link to a Stats SE question) and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89010/ (in particular has several ArcGIS tools mentioned).

Comment: Thanks for comment. I found `Expert gps` but it sharewere. Found a `gpstk library` but not found examples how to work with it. Much interesting `pca` and `principal curves` methods. But can't find a algorithm description for geodata. If you know one it's will nice.

Comment: @KliverMax have you found a solution for this; I guess I've posted a very [similar question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147181/a-method-for-noise-reduction-in-gps-derived-cycling-routes) under the noise tag. Thus if you have an answer and post it; it could be useful.